# Brute Force AWS IAM MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services

Question: Given that a bad actor gains access to a user's aws_access_key_id as well as the aws_secret_access_key stored within ~/.aws/credentials file, will the actor be able to quickly gain access to that user provided that MFA is required? (i.e. does AWS implement some sort of backoff related to failed MFA attempts?)

Assumptions: the actor does not have access to the MFA device but is able to programmatically iterate through all possible MFA code values as well as attempt a login for each possible MFA value.

Comment: To clarify, I assume that it would be the case that there is a limit on the number of failed attempts but I cannot find any documentation which details this feature.

Comment: im unsure but security would be a better way to go to asl this question, it is imho a goos one but maybe not best fitting on serverfault.com

Comment: I think it's fine for SF, I just don't know the answer. Interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to quickly gain access. From what I can see, you only get 5 guesses [with regard to the MFA code] every 4 minutes. After too many failed attempts, AWS will temporarily lock the IAM user. This means that all further attempts to access that user would be pointless as even a correct MFA code will still not allow you access.